# Creating non-admin account

Tags: magento2, admin, user

How to create non-admin accounts in Magento 2 which user can only add and edit products and categories.

Answer (score 1):

> Without creating any admin user, you cannot add and update the product
>   except the API.

For your requirement, *I suggest that create an admin user and create admin role, Using admin rules, you can restrict an admin user.*

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/permissions-user-roles.html